# Get the ID of my clicked product

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I'm new to this site and wondering if somebody could help. I'm creating a website using bootstrap. I added some products in my DB and have used a while loop to display them on the page.

If you click on one of the products it takes you too a new page which should display all the information from only that product.

```
if ($select_db) {

                $SQL = "SELECT * FROM products";
                $result = mysql_query($SQL);
                ?>

                <?php
                $c = 0;
                $id = -1; // The counter
                $n = 3; // Each Nth iteration would be a new table row
                while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    $itemName = $db_field['name'];
                    $itemDescription = $db_field['description'];
                    $itemPrice = $db_field['price'];
                    $myPic = $db_field['image_name'];

                    if ($c % $n == 0 && $c != 0) { // If $c is divisible by $n...
                        echo '<div class="row" ></div>';
                    }
                    $c++;
                    $id++;
                    ?>

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;" id = 1>
                        <a href="productInfo.php"> 
                            <p> <?php echo $c ?> </p>
                            <h2> <?php echo $itemName ?> </h2>
                            <p><img class="img-responsive" img src= '<?php echo $myPic ?>' alt="Oops, Image cannot be found!" height="300" width="300"/></p>
                            <h3><?php echo $itemDescription ?></h3>
                            <p><?php echo $itemPrice ?></p>
                            <div id="selector" class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="<?php $id ?>">Add</button>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            $productsArray[] = array(
                                "id" => $id,
                                "itemName" => $itemName,
                                "itemDescription" => $itemDescription,
                                "price" => $itemPrice
                            );
                            //$_SESSION['sessionArray']=$productsArray;
                            ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <?php
```

Now when I click on one of the columns it takes me to productInfo.php. I'm stuck as to how to display the product that is clicked?

I  have added a variable $id which is the same as the array, example array [0] has id of 0, array [1] has id of 1. I think I'm trying to say if ID = 0 then display the results in the array at place [0]. I'm not sure if this helps?

I tried to display just the `$id` for now on `productInfo.php` but it only shows the last `$id` in the array

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION["id"])) {
 $newID = $_SESSION["id"];
 echo $newID;
 }
 ?>
```

I know this because it doesn't know which one I'm selecting. Am I making this too complicated?

Any help would be appreciated greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your while loop I would add:

```
<a href="product_page.php?id='".$id."'">View More</a>
```

This would concatenate the value of `$id++` into the href under each item. Then all you need to do is create a landing page for `product_page.php`, define the $id on that page again and pull the data for that product from the db. You can do this without using any arrays.

**Edit:**

You would define $id on your product_page.php using `$_GET['id']`, as it is in the url, supplied by your href above ^

A good practice to get into whilst in the development stages would be to `echo $id;` to see if it is echoing the correct data from your while loop. If it echo's the correct $id then you can send the $id to the url through the href.

Let me know if this works or not.

**Pulling data from db of your ID:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='".$myID."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$data1 = $row['whatever'];

echo $data1;
```

Comment: Thank you do much this is exactly what I was looking for, however I add:  
    <a href="product_page.php?id='".$id."'">View More</a>

  

When I click on product with ID 1 it shows the page below:

  

    product_page.php?id=%27  
  
404 not Found
The requested URL /product_page.php was not found on this server.  

I changed it to:   

    <a href='product_page.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>'</a>  
  
Now the URL shows: http://localhost/product_page.php?id=1 
for ID 1 which is correct but it says 404 Not found too. any thoughts?

Comment: No worries ;)

Is your `product_page.php` in the same folder as the other?

Comment: Also, if you could mark my answer as correct you'd be doing me a favor in return ;)

Comment: Sorry about the messy comment was trying to format it!  Yes it is, I can go to localhost/product_page.php with no issues.  Edit: Wow i'm an idiot, it was productInfo.php now it works!!! Thank you again have also marked your answer as correct!

Comment: Have you tried `echo $id;` where each href should be to see if they're all the right id's?

Comment: Within my products.php page I have:    <?php echo "Id is: ".$id."!"; ?>  This displays the correct ID, however in my productInfo.php page I have:    $_GET['id'];
                echo $id;  but this doesn't display it?

Comment: Because the href isn't sending the $id to the URL on your `product_page.php?`, correct? You should just have `$id = 0` before your while loop, then in your while loop `$id++`, then place the `$id` into your href after the while loop.

Comment: I'm assuming the href is, for ID 2 it displays: http://localhost/productInfo.php?id=2

Comment: I see you've set `$id = -1;`, try changing it to `0`

Comment: When you're on the `productinfo.php?id=2` is it loading the page correctly?

Comment: Perfect! I used: $myID = $_GET['id']; and echo'd $myID. You said earlier I don't need to use an array doing it this way. How would I pull the product from the DB for the ID I clicked on?  Thank you again.

Comment: I just thought that was a stupid question, I'm assuming the easiest way would be to get the product where ID = $myID (page ID ive landed on)?

Comment: I'll update my answer because it looks messy in the comments.